No data return from usb when I use usb4java to read data , why?
Now transferred get correct data size, but no bytes in buffer, why?
public static void handle(short vid, short pid) {
        Device device = findDevice(vid, pid);
        Pair pair = findBulkInEndpoint(device, LibUsb.TRANSFER_TYPE_BULK);
        if (pair == null) {
            System.out.println("No bulk - in endpoint found.");
            return;
        }
        int result;
        DeviceHandle handle = new DeviceHandle();
        result = LibUsb.open(device, handle);
        if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to open device", result);
        }
        try {
            result = LibUsb.claimInterface(handle, pair.interfaceDescriptor.iInterface());
            if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                throw new LibUsbException("Unable to claim interface", result);
            }
            boolean running = true;
            while (running) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(1024).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                IntBuffer transferred = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
                result = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(handle, pair.endpointDescriptor.bEndpointAddress(), buffer, transferred, 10000);
                if (result == 0) {
                    int len = transferred.get();
                    System.out.println("Read " + len);
                    buffer.flip();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
                    buffer.get(bytes, 0, len);  //limit=0, position=0, throw BufferUnderflowException
                    System.out.println(new String(bytes));
                } else {
                    throw new LibUsbException("Bulk transfer error", result);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            LibUsb.close(handle);
        }
    }


buffer.hasArray() does not tell you whether there is data but whether the buffer has an accessible underlying array. It will return false when the buffer is a direct buffer or when the buffer is read-only. So this property depends on what BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(1024) did and will never change. It does not depend on the contained data.

@Holger thank ur answer, but it dose not work if I use buffer.get(bytes, 0, len); to get data, all zero in byte array.

Assuming that bulkTransfer works like other I/O methods, you’d have to call buffer.flip() first, before reading the data from the buffer.

@Holger I tried it. both limit and position are 0, there is no data in array. Somehow no data was written in.

What were the position and limit before you invoked bulkTransfer?

Maybe, bulkTransfer does not behave like normal I/O methods and does not update the buffer position. In that case, getting the data without flip() would do. Since you are reading from a device, it’s not clear whether the data are suitable for converting to a String like new String(bytes). Maybe, a hex dump would be better.

What was the trace output of System.out.println("Read " + len); btw?

@g00se Outputs different integers, I think the size of the data.

You can debug it with System.out.println(java.util.HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ").formatHex(theArray));

You might want to try JavaDoesUSB. It's far easier to use.
The below code assumes that the interface number and endpoint number are known, which is the case for known devices. It can also be detected if needed.
int INTERFACE_NO = 1;
int ENDPOINT_IN = 1;

public static void handle(int vid, int pid) {

    var device = Usb.findDevice(vid, pid).get();
    device.open();
    device.claimInterface(INTERFACE_NO);

    boolean running = true;
    while (running) {
        var bytes = device.transferIn(ENDPOINT_IN);
        System.out.println(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    device.close();
}

Note that JavaDoesUSB is built using the Foreign Function & Memory API. So it requires at least Java 22.

yeah, but jdk1.8 must be used.
